# Other server sockets receive data when sending data to the server sockets

Tags: java, server

First of all, I'm sorry about my English ability.

I'm trying to use multi-thread to connect socket with clients.

My server threads operate separately as multi-threads
and I make different in socket port number each client just in case.

However when I connect a client when another client is already connected,
data from the initial client is sent to late client's server socket.

For example:
client1 send data to its own server socket periodically.
however when client2 is connected, client2's server socket take that data instead of client1's server socket.

Here's the server thread code.

```java
public class serverthread extends Thread {
    int  num;
    static Socket socket;
    static InputStream in;
    static DataInputStream dis;

    public serverthread(Socket s, int num) {
        this.socket = s;
        this.num = num;
        try {
            in = socket.getInputStream();
            dis = new DataInputStream(in);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            log.loglist.add("1exit(interect) : " + socket.getInetAddress());
        }
    }

    public void run() {
        try {
            while (true) {
                int come = dis.readInt();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            server.endsocket(num);
        }
    }
}
```

It seems to me that it's obvious that the socket is different, but it's sending data to the wrong socket.
Is it supposed to be like this? Or am I coding wrong?

Comment: Consider posting a [mcve]. Then I can try to reproduce your problem which will, hopefully, lead me to a solution for it.